# Overriding ListViewItem shrinks all my items in the listview

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have a ListViewItem style that I want to apply on the items (I just want to disable the disabled color Trigger on the listboxitems because it is ugly until/when I find a new color that I like better.

```
              <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
                      <Border 
                        Name="Border"
                        Padding="2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        >
                        <GridViewRowPresenter
                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                          />
                      </Border>
                      <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                          <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                  Property="Background" Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"
                                  />
                        </Trigger>
                      </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
```

However, upon adding this template to the listview, the items all shrink. Originally they were getting their item size from this binding (I think): Height={Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}.  However, I don't see any reason why adding an itemcontainer style would break this binding unless gridviewpresenter is doing something strange.

```
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
            ItemsSource ="{Binding Path = bits}"
            DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:BusViewModel}"
            >

              <Components:CenteredTextBlock
                x:Name="CommentTextBlock"
                BorderBrush="{Binding RelativeSource ={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=BorderBrush}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Height="{Binding ElementName=graph_viewer, Path=GraphHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                >
                <Components:CenteredTextBlock.MainText>
                  <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringConcatConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Alias" />
                    <Binding Path="SignalValueAtPrimaryMarker" />
                  </MultiBinding>
                </Components:CenteredTextBlock.MainText>
              </Components:CenteredTextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

CenteredTexTBlock is just a centered text block (wanted to save having to type out grid and write in alignment = center repeatedly).

```
<Grid>
  <TextBlock 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Components:CenteredTextBlock}}, Path=Foreground}" 
    Text="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Components:CenteredTextBlock}}, Path=MainText}" 
    />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default template of `ListViewItem` has `ContentPresenter` and not `GridViewRowPresenter`.

In case you only want to disable selection Trigger and want your's brush over there, so i would suggest to have default ControlTemplate only with your set of Triggers in it.

Default template goes like this with your triggers:

```
<ControlTemplate
    TargetType="ListViewItem">
    <Border
        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
        Padding="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
        Name="Bd"
        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ContentPresenter
           Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
           ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
           ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
           HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
           VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
           SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
           <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                   Property="Background"
                   Value="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrush}"/>
       </Trigger>
     </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
 </ControlTemplate>
```